# pod lib lint fails with bitcode error

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I have created custom control for tvOS (https://github.com/Ponf/FPScrollingBanner) and I'm trying to publish it in cocoapods repository. When I'm checking podspec using `pod lib lint` it fails with next log:

```
Integrating target `Pods` (`../../../../var/folders/9w/9v94b0_j4l1b_802_my5vlc00000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/App.xcodeproj` project)
  Adding Build Phase 'Embed Pods Frameworks' to project.
  Adding Build Phase 'Copy Pods Resources' to project.
  Adding Build Phase 'Check Pods Manifest.lock' to project.
  - Running post install hooks
  Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
   Building with xcodebuild.
xcodebuild clean build -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme App -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=- -sdk appletvsimulator
Build settings from command line:
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = -
    SDKROOT = appletvsimulator9.1

=== CLEAN TARGET FPScrollingBanner OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
target 'FPScrollingBanner' has bitcode disabled (ENABLE_BITCODE = NO), but it is required for the 'appletvos' platform

** CLEAN FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
=== BUILD TARGET FPScrollingBanner OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
target 'FPScrollingBanner' has bitcode disabled (ENABLE_BITCODE = NO), but it is required for the 'appletvos' platform

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
 -> FPScrollingBanner (1.0.0)
    - ERROR | [tvOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.

Pods workspace available at `/var/folders/9w/9v94b0_j4l1b_802_my5vlc00000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/App.xcworkspace` for inspection.

[!] FPScrollingBanner did not pass validation, due to 1 error.

/Users/filipp/projects/CocoaPods/lib/cocoapods/command/lib.rb:181:in `block in run'
/Users/filipp/projects/CocoaPods/lib/cocoapods/command/lib.rb:153:in `each'
/Users/filipp/projects/CocoaPods/lib/cocoapods/command/lib.rb:153:in `run'
/Users/filipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bundler/gems/CLAide-4ded02e52c34/lib/claide/command.rb:312:in `run'
/Users/filipp/projects/CocoaPods/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in `run'
/Users/filipp/projects/CocoaPods/bin/pod:44:in `<main>'
```

So as I can see, the problem is `target 'FPScrollingBanner' has bitcode disabled (ENABLE_BITCODE = NO), but it is required for the 'appletvos' platform`. When I'm opening `App.workspace` with Xcode, it has no `bitcode` option at all.

**Xcode version:** 7.2

**Cocoapods** built from latest master branch with specifying latest CocoaPods Core.

Answer (score 0):

I have fallback to cocoapods version `0.39.0` and bug doesn't reproduced anymore. It looks like something broken in current master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set *.podspec file:

```
s.xcconfig = {
   'ENABLE_BITCODE' => 'NO'
}
```

in my *.podspec ,add this will set the framework BITCODE disable.